# How to restrict previous date display in custom forms?

Tags: forms, 8

I created a custom module for a form which accepts **from date** and **to date** as user input. I would like to restrict the user from selecting a date prior to current date.

**Code snippet of my code**

```
$form['oneway']['from_date'] = array (
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => t('From Date'),
  '#date_year_range' => '-80:0',
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: what does your from date look like? `d/m/Y 18/01/2016` ? OR ???

Answer (score 2):

***Approach to get today's date as Minimum date***

Pass the JS options in '`#datepicker_options`'

```
$form['oneway']['from_date'] = array(
  '#title' => t('From Date'),
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
  '#date_year_range' => '-80:0',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#datepicker_options' => array(
    'minDate' => 0,
  ),
);
```

> minDate => 0 (Sets the min date to today's date)
>
> minDate => -1 (Sets the min date to yesterday's date)

More info: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: HI Gaurav, Thanks for your replay i have deployed the code in my form,but the date picker in my form is not visible. I am using drupal 8, are there any changes to be made in drupal 8

Comment: date_popup is not working in drupal 8 ???

Answer (score 0):

```
    $form['oneway']['from_date'] = array(
      '#title' => t('From Date'),
      '#type' => 'datetime',
      '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
      '#date_year_range' => '-80:0',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => [
        'min' =>  \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format(REQUEST_TIME, 'custom', 'Y-m-d'),
    ],
    );
```

**date_popup** is not going to work in drupal 8.x, use **datetime**